# JavaScript multiple return types

Tags: javascript, json

I want to be able to call a function in JavaScript and return a primitive value, but also data. For instance, let's say I want to validate a password. Sometimes I want to know if it's valid or not (meets minimum requirements), and sometimes I want to know how strong it is, and other times I want to know how strong it is in words ("weak, strong,", etc.).

So basically I want this to be valid:

`if (validate.checkPassword(password)) ...`

but also this to work:

```
if (validate.checkPassword(password).strength === "strong")
if (validate.checkPassword(password).rating >= 6)
```

Since an object can both be a function have data, can a JSON return value both have a primitive type base value, and other data members?

Comment: Couldn't you just return `false` for non-valid password, an an object with the desired parameters for valid passwords (As all objects are interpreted as `true` in JavaScript boolean context)

Comment: Don't call `validate.checkPassword(password)` more than once!

Answer (score 2):

```
return { strength: 'abc', rating: -1 }
```

Truthyness in javascript will make the if statement work, then you can inspect the JSON for any values needed.

Answer (score 2):

No, things can not be multiple typed.  However, you could add a boolean to that data structure

```
if (validate.isValidPassword(passWord).isValid)...
```

but you should strongly reconsider your nomenclature, as that is some confusing stuff up there.

Otherwise, `null` is falsey, so if you only use the latter statements inside a block where it is valid, then you should have no problem.

Answer (score 2):

First off, JSON is just the notation of a JavaScript object not what the object itself is called. Within JavaScript (unserialized) it's just an object.

With that said, it seems like you want to return an object back from your validation method which would then expose the various information you're looking to return. e.g.

```
function isValidPassword(pw){
  var result = {
    strength: 'weak',
    rating: 0,
    valid: false
  };

  // test and change result.strength, result.rating and result.valid
  // based on the input

  return result;
}
```

This is an either/or scenario so you can't return "true/false" and get that extra meta information. Note that any object returned would result in a `true` result when tested, so given the above:

```
var validPassword = validate.isValidPassword(null);

// always true, we have an object
if (validPassword){
}

// instead, you'd now need to check:
if (validPassword.valid){
}
```

*(I'll also disregard that a name like `isValidPassword` implies a true/false result and not an object result so if you're making a common library I'd encourage you to rename the function if you plan to change the result)*

However, you can make multiple methods to break out the level of detail you're looking for, which makes a simple `isValidPassword` work as intended, but then add functionality like `getPasswordStrength`, `getPasswordRating`, etc.:

```
function isValidPassword(pw){
  // return true/false;
}
function getPasswordStrength(pw){
  // return "weak","strong",etc.
}
function getPasswordRating(pw){
  // return 1,2,etc.
}
```

This also keeps the implied results a little more legible in terms of readability while still offering alternatives to getting the information you're looking for.

```
if (!validator.isValidPassword(pw)){
  error = pw + ' is unacceptable (' + validator.getPasswordStrength(pw) + ')';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can only return one 'thing' from your function, but the function can contain other 'things'.

I think your best result would be to return an object along these lines:

```
{
    valid: 
    strength: 
    rating: 
}
```

Then you could do what you're wanting above, with the exception of the default type where you'd need to do:

```
if (validate.isValidPassword(password).valid)
```

EDIT: As a slight justification to returning an object each time. In my mind I had imagined you would always want to check the state of why a password was valid or not. Simply returning false would give you the y/n for whether it passed, but wouldn't give you the info you'd need to establish 'why' the password was not valid.
If you wanted to display some 'you must include uppercase, lowercase and ensure that the first letter was typed on a Monday' type message then it would seem sensible to return the password 'result' object in every situation. Just seems more flexible to me.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
function PasswordInfo(strength, rating)
{
    this.strength = strength;
    this.rating = rating;
}

function isValidPassword(password)
{
    return new PasswordInfo('strong', 10);
}

function validate()
{
    var info = isValidPassword('password');

    if (info.strength === 'strong' && info.rating >== 6)
    {
        alert('good password);
    }
    else
    {
        alert('bad password);
    }
}
```

The function `PasswordInfo` in this instance is actually a class/constructor.